# In Expo iOS: How to ask Wireless permission before using it

Tags: ios, permissions, expo

I am new to Expo and new to iOS. I am now building an app for iOS. The app uses a react-native-WebView component at the first page when opening the app. The WebView requires network to work.

I have two questions regarding this scenario:

1. How to request this permission before using it?
2. How to detect user grants or not?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same question/issue

Comment: @razor7 my workaround is: use `import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";`.  then check `state.isConnected` in the callback of `NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {})`. If it's true then do your normal business; otherwise, show a button leads user to System settings page for granting network permission.

Comment: Thanks! I use that actually but I thought that there was a new permission to set and to listen to. Can you share the code to go to that system setting page of the app?

Comment: @razor7 Here you go! if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      Linking.openURL("app-settings:");
    } else {
      Linking.openSettings();
    }